# Executing a file a large number of times

Tags: python-2.7

How do I get a file to run a large number of times, say even a million? For instance, randomly choose a number from a list a million times and find it's average. Example:

```
fib = [2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
i = random.choice(fib)
print i
```

I want the average of a million trials. It seems like the method around here is to help and not so much feed me the answer. That is greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about looping a million times, summing up the chosen values and dividing by a million:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random

n = 1e6
fib = [2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
print(sum(random.choice(fib) for _ in range(int(n))) / n)
```

Output:

```
25.565039
```

The above code contains a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression). It is equivalent to this loop version:

```
sum_ = 0
for x in range(int(n)):
    sum_ += random.choice(fib)
print(sum_/n)
```

Output:

```
25.576006
```